# PHP Shared Memory not working in lighttpd just in the shell

Tags: php, server, shared-memory

I'm having problems with Shmop on PHP. When I run a simple code in shell, i can write and read what i want in memory, but, using the same scripts by the server and nothing happen.

This is my code (write.php)

```
<?php
$KEY = 672213396;
$smid = shmop_open($KEY, "c", 0644, 5);
$text = "test";
echo shmop_write($smid, $text, 0);
?>
```

(read.php)

```
<?php
$KEY = 672213396;
$smid = shmop_open($KEY, "a", 0644, 100);
echo shmop_read($smid,0,5);
?>
```

My system: Raspberry PI A+, Raspbian Jessy, PHP 5.6.30-0+deb8u1 (cli), lightpd with mod fastcgi and mod fastcgi-php enabled.

Comment: A first step could be trying to print the return code of [shmop_open()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shmop-open.php) if it returns False it is likely an indication of a permission issue.

Comment: (mod_fastcgi.c.2702) FastCGI-stderr: PHP Warning:  shmop_open(): unable to attach or create shared memory segment

Comment: ipcs -m


------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status      
0x28112994 0          pi         644        15         0                       
0x28112995 32769      www-data   644        15         0

Answer (score 1):

The problem is really simple to solve.

First, we must map the share memory:

```
pi@raspberrypi:$ ipcs -m

------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status                           
0x28112995 32769      www-data   644        15         0                       
0x28112996 65538      www-data   666        15         0
```

When i run the code in the first time i used 0644 as a permission, but the user from webserver "www-data" and my shell user "pi" can't access and write in this memory table just because the permission.

So, in my case, i just set the permissions to work fine, the "pi" user have rights to write and "www-data" just open the memory to read it.